# Are "muted" and "volume = 0.0" the same? Event Listener treats them differently

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to coding and I've come to a problem I'm not finding a solution to. I'm making a little media player that I plan to use with athletes I coach. My idea is to force them to listen to my comments on game film they watch. So the player pauses if it's volume is too low.  I've made it so playback pauses when the volume is reduced to below 10%. However, when the mute button(in the default HTML5 media player) is pressed, playback does not pause.

So are muted and a volume of 0.0 not the same? When I bring the slider all the way down to zero(I can only do this without the alert, or else it gets stuck at 0.1 when the alert fires), the volume/mute button shows mute. But I'm sure that's because I have to pass the 0.1 threshold the event listener is looking for.

This is what my code looks like

```
video.addEventListener("volumechange", function() {
        if (video.volume < 0.1) {
            video.pause();
            alert('Video Paused: Volume too low');
        }   
    });
```

I plan to customize the controls of my player anyway, so I think I'll be able to make it work with onclick events pretty easily, but I felt this bit of confusion was worth figuring out in the meantime.

So are volume slider changes all that's included in the volumechange event? Or is there a way to make it so the muted state is recognized by the volumechange event listener? Or a way to make a separate one for muted?(which I know is not an event.)  Or should I just table it until I make my custom controls?

Thanks.

Comment: PS. How does this prevent the user from just turning the device volume down or off?

Comment: `Mute` has different behavior than `volume`. According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-muted),  `volume` is simply stating the volume of the media element, while `mute` is stating it on media resources and potentially overriding user preferences..

Comment: @Marty it doesn't, but there will be more to the project than just volume based play/pause. I have some ideas that are a little devious, and I'm just sort of learning to code as I try to implement them. 

Thanks again for your help. I'm sure I'll need it again soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [description for the `volumechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) says:

> Sent when the audio volume changes (both when the volume is set *and when the muted attribute is changed*).

Assuming this is accurate, your event handler will trigger on mute and unmute, so it should just be a matter of using the [`muted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-muted) attribute in your `if` statement:

```
if (video.volume < 0.1 || video.muted) {
    // Pause.
}
```

The value of `volume` is independent of `muted` and does not change when you mute or unmute.

Comment: Huh. I thought I tried it with muted on its own before ever using the volumechange event listener. I just plugged the muted attribute in now and it worked exactly as intended. I must have screwed something else up. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ErikA Why a `< 0.1` check ? Is `0.09` muted for you ? (browsers which show an playing icon on the tabs with sound will hide it when the volume is set to `0`

Comment: @Marty, I'm just wondering if OP knows that `volume` has more granularity than just `.1` .

Comment: @Kaiido All good, your comment seemed targeted at me until you edited.

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't know that I could use a second decimal place. .09 is not muted, but for the purposes of the project I don't want it to be able to be set quiet enough that it can be easily ignored by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just use both `video.volume` and `video.muted` together:

```
if (video.volume < 0.1 || video.muted) {

//your logic

}
```